# Class.getResourceAsStream in Robolectric environment fails to return correct stream in M platform

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I've got a problem with switching to `M` platform in robolectric runner.

`Class.getResourceAsStream` seems to perform differently when using `Build.VERSION_CODES.M` and `Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1`

My application uses [PhoneUtils](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library that loads its metadata using the following code:

```
static final MetadataLoader DEFAULT_METADATA_LOADER = new MetadataLoader() {
   @Override
   public InputStream loadMetadata(String metadataFileName) {
     return MetadataManager.class.getResourceAsStream(metadataFileName);
   }
};
```

When configuring test with:

```
@Config(
        constants = BuildConfig::class,
        sdk = intArrayOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
)
```

resulting `JarUrlConnection` is set to:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection:jar:file:/C:/Users/motorro/.m2/repository/org/robolectric/android-all/6.0.0_r1-robolectric-0/android-all-6.0.0_r1-robolectric-0.jar!/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/data/PhoneNumberMetadataProto_US
```

(refers roboelectric platform mock) and fails to read a file.

If configured with:

```
@Config(
        constants = BuildConfig::class,
        sdk = intArrayOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
)
```

resulting `JarUrlConnection` is set to:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection:jar:file:/C:/Users/motorro/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.0.0/ce021971974ee6a26572e43eaba7edf184c3c63d/libphonenumber-8.0.0.jar!/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/data/PhoneNumberMetadataProto_US
```

which points to correct library file (test passes).

Here is the test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class ExampleUnitTest {
    companion object {
        private val PHONE: Phonenumber.PhoneNumber

        init {
            PHONE = Phonenumber.PhoneNumber()
            PHONE.countryCode = 7
            PHONE.nationalNumber = 4956360636
        }
    }


    @Test
    @Config(
            constants = BuildConfig::class,
            sdk = intArrayOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    )
    fun withLollipop() {
        PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().format(PHONE, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
    }

    @Test
    @Config(
            constants = BuildConfig::class,
            sdk = intArrayOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    )
    fun withM() {
        PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().format(PHONE, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL)
    }
}
```

Is it a roboelectric problem or do I miss some configuration here?

**The duct-tape solution** for now is to `@Config` all failing tests individually.

Current dependencies:

```
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.4"
```

[Here](https://github.com/motorro/RoboClassLoaderTest) is a whole test project for your convenience.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2773)

Comment: Unfortunately, don't have much information. From error description, it looks like Android M includes the google phone library. How to force class path to put your compile dependency before `android.jar` is challenging task

Comment: @EugenMartynov Seems so as some _other_ library file when loaded the same way produces correct path. Also the phone library still needs to be declared as a dependency explicitly - not exported from android framework. And just noticed that library [README](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/README.md) tells it has been used in Android _since 4.0_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed in [Robolectric 3.2.2](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-3.2.2)